# How to set added item as active object?

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I'm using the following to add text to my fabricjs canvas and I was wondering how I could have it be automatically selected when the onclick is triggered?

```
// Add text
function Addtext() {
   canvas.add(new fabric.IText('Tap and Type', {
      left: 50,
      top: 100,
   }));
}
```

---

```
<button onclick="Addtext()">+ Text</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `canvas.setActiveObject()`. [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5KKQ2/2518/)

```
var canvas  = new fabric.Canvas('c');

function Addtext() {
   var text = new fabric.IText('Tap and Type', {
      left: 50,
      top: 100,
   });
   canvas.add(text);
   canvas.setActiveObject(text);
}
$('#add').click(Addtext);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should work with : object added and set the object active like this ;

```
canvas.on({
        'object:added': function(e) {
              e.set('active',true); 
            }
        }
```

Or, you juste need to put your object in a variable, and then set it to active.

Comment: Why do it this way, when there is a built in method for the fabric.Canvas object - not that this may necessarily be a bad way?